# I have a problem with the scanner in Java

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with my scanner in the main method. I know that this topic has been addressed before, but everything I've tried doesn't solve my problem. I hope you can help me.

```
import java.utill.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        Grades grade = new Grades(4, 2);


        System.out.println("1 is finished");

        System.out.println("2 is starting");

        int n = c.nextInt();

        System.out.println("2.1 is starting");

        int gr;
        for (int i = grade.getTotal(); i < grade.getTotal() + n; i++) {
            gr = c.nextInt();
            grade.setGrades(gr, i, grade.getTotal() + n);
        }

        System.out.println("2 is finished");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("3 is starting");

        for (int i = 0; i < grade.getTotal(); i++) {
        System.out.println(grade.getGrade(i));
        }

        System.out.println("3 is finished");
        System.out.println();

        c.close();
    }


}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {

    public Grades(int total, int totalCurriculum) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        setTotalCurriculum(totalCurriculum);
        setTotal(total);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            this.grades[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    
        sc.close();
    }
    
    public void setGrades(int grade, int index, int total) {
        this.grades[index] = grade;
        if (index < total) {
            setTotal(this.total + total);
        }
    }
    
    public int getGrade(int nr) {
        return grades[nr];
    }
    
    public int getLocalAverage(int nr) {
        return localAverage[nr];
    }
    
    public float globalAverageCalc(int[] localAverage) {
        int sum = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < getTotal(); i++) {
            sum = sum + getGrade(i);
        }
    
        return (float) sum / getTotalCurriculum();
    }

}
```

When i try to input the int value for `int n` (under `System.out.println("2 is starting");`) the error appears and the program stops.

This is the console output:

```
5
4
7
9
1 is finished
2 is starting
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:945)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2267)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2221)
    at Test.Main.main(Main.java:22)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes!! Thank you very much. It makes sense now why it wasn't working